# Role to assign to Lambda function (was: Check the logs when building Lambda functions with Go)

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, logging, aws-lambda

I'm following the official [Building Lambda functions with Go](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-golang.html) to its [`blank-go/`](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/blob/main/sample-apps/blank-go) demo, from which you can see that the `handleRequest` function almost use `log.Print` in its whole process:

```golang
func handleRequest(ctx context.Context, event events.SQSEvent) (string, error) {
    // event
    eventJson, _ := json.MarshalIndent(event, "", "  ")
    log.Printf("EVENT: %s", eventJson)
    // environment variables
    log.Printf("REGION: %s", os.Getenv("AWS_REGION"))
    log.Println("ALL ENV VARS:")
    for _, element := range os.Environ() {
        log.Println(element)
    }
    // request context
    lc, _ := lambdacontext.FromContext(ctx)
    log.Printf("REQUEST ID: %s", lc.AwsRequestID)
    // global variable
    log.Printf("FUNCTION NAME: %s", lambdacontext.FunctionName)
    // context method
    deadline, _ := ctx.Deadline()
    log.Printf("DEADLINE: %s", deadline)
. . .
```

However, I didn't find where I can read those logs. Please help.

**UPDATE:**

I've ran/tested my [`blank-go/`](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/blob/main/sample-apps/blank-go) function many times, but each time I click on the log link from my test:

[image]

I'm getting an empty view:

[image]

IE, *"There are no log streams."*

So I ***am*** checking the right place, thus now the question becomes, why there is no log *despite* that I've ran my test *several times*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the Lambda logging prerequisites information in [the official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-cloudwatchlogs.html). Specifically, you need to assign a role to the Lambda function that has access to create logs in CloudWatch. Amazon provides a role named `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` for Lambda functions that includes the necessary permissions to send logs to CloudWatch.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda logs are in [Cloudwatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-logs-api.html). You can follow [this AWS guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-cloudwatchlogs.html) to access them. You can also use [SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-logging.html) but that works a little differently. AWS also has a page for [Lambda logging in Go](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/golang-logging.html).

You can view logs in Cloudwatch in two ways, from the Console or from command line. If you use Console, refer to [this guide by AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/monitoring-aws-lambda-errors-using-amazon-cloudwatch/). On command line, you can modify this bash script to take parameters.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
aws lambda invoke --function-name my-function --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --payload '{"key": "value"}' out
sed -i'' -e 's/"//g' out
sleep 15
aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name /aws/lambda/my-function --log-stream-name stream1 --limit 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I am checking the right place, thus now the question has changed, please see my updated OP. Sorry for responding late, somehow SO stopped sending me any notices as before...

Answer (score 0):

And please note that AWS has not yet updated all docs.
The recommended runtime for GO has changed:
https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/compute/migrating-aws-lambda-functions-from-the-go1-x-runtime-to-the-custom-runtime-on-amazon-linux-2/
And more things AWS did not tell you:
https://www.go-on-aws.com/lambda-go/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I am checking the right place, thus now the question has changed, please see my updated OP.

Answer (score 0):

The Lambda console just takes some time to show the log. Directly at cloudwatch console it is faster displayed.
Or use the great https://github.com/TylerBrock/saw from cli.
This will not magically let logs appear, its just a handy tool.

With Lambda Functions there is always at least the „START,…REPORT“ entries, unless the function does not have the cloudwatch rights in the role policy.

Usually this takes just seconds.
Check the Lambda permissions [image: Permissions]

As there is a log group, the first policy seems to be there.

Could you provide this screenshot from the lambda console, expanding the first picture? At the bottom it also shows the log.
Example:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I saw two issues. First, _"The Lambda console just takes some time to show the log"_, I know that, but that _"some time"_ is only in the range of several minutes. However, if you see my cloudwatch log, you'll see that it is empty. IE, the run that I did the days before are even not showing anything there. Thus, secondly, if the cloudwatch log itself is empty, then I don't think any 3rd party tools can magically show my logs in their output. Anyway, thanks for all the answers, I upvoted your other (first) answer just to show my token of appreciation of your helps.